# How to make sure a string is both an eight digit number and also not eight alphabets

Tags: python

So Im supposed to write a program that does the following
•   Read an eight-digit integer entered by the user. If less or more then eight digits are entered prompt the user again for input
Ive tried the following methods yet they dont work, what do I do. Either it accepts asdfghjk as an eight digit number or it crashes the entire loop

```
number= input("Enter an eight digit number")
while True:
  if len(number)==8 and number.isnumeric():
     continue;
  else:
     number=input("Invalid Entry, Type again:")
```

```
number = int(input("Enter an eight digit number:"))
while True:
  if number < 10000000 or number > 99999999:
      number = input("Invalid Entry, Type again:")
  else:
     continue
```

Comment: why are you using `continue` ? you dont need it and why is there a  `;` ?

Comment: Here is an examples and explination of how and where to use [continue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loop_control.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the "continue" command wrong.
Continue jumps to the next iteration, e.g. starts again at the while loop. You should exchange it to "break", which breaks out of the loop continuing with the code after the while loop.

Edit: and also you can delete the semicolon after continue. There is no need for semicolons in python.

Answer (score 1):

What do you wanna do if its 8 digit number? If u want to quit the loop, replace `continue;` by `break`

Answer (score 0):

Use a single `input()` and place it inside the loop.

Then in this case I prefer the option to `break` when it's OK - rather than `continue` when it's not.

```py
while True:
    number = input("Enter an eight digit number")
    if len(number)==8 and number.isnumeric():
        break
print(f"{number=}")
```